# Add Ext.Net.Gridpanel in code behind

Tags: c#, ext.net

I'm trying to build several gridpanels with the result of a search in the DB.

But they never appears...

Here is my code, what's wrong with it ?

http://pastebin.com/WuTZwZrP

**EDIT**

Ok, got it. For those who have the same problem, I solved it by adding this to the GridPanel :

```
RenderTo = this.ExtPanel.ClientID
```

And this after the build :

```
ext.GridPanel grid = this.BuildGridPanel(forwarder.Key, forwarder.Value);
grid.Render();
//this.ExtPanel.Controls.Add(grid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void AddGridPanel()
        {
          Ext.Net.GridPanel g=new Ext.Net.GridPanel();
          Ext.Net.Store store1=new Ext.Net.Store();
          Model model = new Model();
          for (int i = 1; i < tas.getTaskDE().Count / 2; i++)
                {
                    fields = fields + "," + tas.getTaskDE()[i].FieldName;
                    ModelField modelField = new ModelField();
                    modelField.Name = tas.getTaskDE()[i].FieldName;
                    model.Fields.Add(modelField);

                    if (tas.getTaskDE()[i].Visibility == "true")
                    {
                        g.ColumnModel.Columns.Add(new ColumnBase[] { 
                        new Column 
                          {
                             Text = tas.getTaskDE()[i].FieldADName,
                             DataIndex = tas.getTaskDE()[i].FieldName,
                             Flex = 1
                          },
                         });
                    }
                }
          SqlDataSource s = new SqlDataSource();
          s.ConnectionString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
          s.SelectCommand = query;
          store1.Model.Add(model);
          store1.DataSource = s;
          store1.DataBind();
          g.Store.Add(store1);
          g.Render(this.Form);
        }
```

this an example of dynamic gridpanel hope it helps